# How to create block-helper in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In Ember-CLI I need to create a block helper like this

```
 {{#the-helper attribute="this is attribute" }}
     <b> this is bold string </b>
 {{/the-helper}}
```

the-helper will call another helper internally.

Comment: I think you need to create `component` not a helper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a component is the way to go.

To call a component in its block form (and being able to pass content into it) the component template needs to contain the `{{yield}}` tag, and anything passed inside the component block would be displayed in the template.

If you generate a new component with "`ember generate component my-component`", the component's template will already include the `{{yield}}` tag by default. If you want to add it to an existing component just add the tag yourself to the component's template file.

To pass content into it you just then need to call

```
{{#my-component}}
  {{link-to 'MyLinkText' 'my-route-name.sub-route'}}
{{/my-component}}
```

Check the docs for more detailed information: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/

Comment: So I want to call link-to helper in the component is it possible ?

Comment: Sure, that couldn't be any easier. Just generate a component with Ember-CLI with "ember generate component my-component"

Then when calling your component just do:
{{#my-component}}
 {{link-to 'MyLinkText' 'routeName.subRoute'}}
{{/my-component}}

Comment: but I want to compute the linkText which will have a number

Comment: my route name is not fixed it is dynamic and the segments are also dynamic